# The boundaries of the <BODY> and <DIV>s are offset upon resize. How do I fix?

Tags: layout, html, wrapper, offset

well, I've got a straightforward layout,
but there is a problem with boundaries,
when I resize the window, the content gets outside the boundaries.

that's how it looks like:
[Boundaries offset http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/1893/aproblem.png](http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/1893/aproblem.png)

I'd would be glad if you could offer a solution...

Dunno what's causing it.

Note, please don't change the wrapper thing, for that's really the only layout that worked for my site... But I think its possible to modify the header and the foot, or perhaps put some more wrappers, if I only knew where.

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
border:3px solid #FFAD17;
background-color:#FFF;
border-radius:7px;
font:9.5pt Tahoma;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
html {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

div.header{
    background-image:url('http://img804.imageshack.us/img804/4743/testcj.png');
    background-position:top;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    padding: 3px;
    }
div.wrapper{
    float:left;
    }
div.context_wrapper{
    margin-left:158px;
    padding: 3px;   
    }
div.context{
    float:left;
    }
div.menu{
    text-align:center;
    padding: 3px;
    width:140px;
    float:left;     
    }
div.footer{
    background-image:url('http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/9422/test2fy.png');
    background-position:bottom;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    width:auto;
    padding: 3px;
    clear:both;     
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="header">Head</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu">Menu</div>
    <div class="context_wrapper">
        <div class="context">
            ContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContentContent
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Foot</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: apply some width to that context so it wont move out.

Comment: I cannot, I don't know the width. Its different depending to the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above seems to work perfectly on my computer.
However, if you are getting this problem on resize, try applying `min-width` to the div containing the background, and try again.

Comment: I cannot, I don't know the width. Its different depending to the content.

Comment: Try using a fluid width for the header and footer, where  the background property is set.
Try `.header, .footer{min-width:100%}`

Comment: Well it's all the same, I wonder how it works on your machine. For me, when I pull the scrollbar, there it goes like on the picture posted. I tried on both IE9 and Chrome - both show identical thing.